# Evaluate best model

Tags: machine-learning-model, overfitting

Let's assume I have 2 models

Model 1:

- Train Accuracy = 92.4%
- Validation Accuracy = 37.6%
- Test Accuracy = 35.3%

Model 2:

- Train Accuracy = 37.0%
- Validation Accuracy = 34.2%
- Test Accuracy = 34.1%

Which is the best model ?
Model 1 is heavily overfitting but the final performance is better

Comment: Oof, I forgot that I can't just propose a duplicate now.  Let me know if the linked question doesn't help, and I'll reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Deep learning models heavily rely on stochastic processes such as weight initialization, back-propagation, etc. For evaluation and comparison of different models, there are methods that are generally referred to as [Cross-Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)). The most popular type of CV is the [k-Fold CV](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/), and if your model training comprises hyperparameter tuning, you must use the [Nested k-Fold CV](https://machinelearningmastery.com/nested-cross-validation-for-machine-learning-with-python/).